# Possible to put Logic App Run History Identifier inside logic app action input field?

Tags: azure, identifier, azure-logic-apps

Hi i was searching on if there is any way to put the logic app identifier into a logic app actions input field?

Is it possible to retrieve it some how?

[image]

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Found it!

```
@{workflow()['run']['name']}
```

Worked like a charm.

Comment: Just FYI, the same data is also in any outgoing request originated from the Logic Apps. It's in header "X-Ms-Workflow-Run-Id".

Comment: Just to add that regarding the outgoing headers, there are a couple more that might give you more insight also: x-ms-execution-location, x-ms-workflow-id, x-ms-workflow-version, x-ms-workflow-name, x-ms-workflow-system-id, x-ms-workflow-run-id, x-ms-workflow-run-tracking-id, x-ms-workflow-operation-name, x-ms-workflow-subscription-id, x-ms-workflow-resourcegroup-name, x-ms-tracking-id, x-ms-correlation-id, x-ms-client-request-id, x-ms-client-tracking-id, x-ms-action-tracking-id, x-ms-activity-vector.

Comment: In the context of Microsoft Flow, the syntax seems to be `workflow().run.name`

Comment: workflow()['run']['name'] in expression works for me

Comment: For posterity, the @{workflow()['run']['name']} syntax is used in the 'Code View' and the workflow()['run']['name'] syntax is used in 'App Designer' expressions.  The @{} wraps the expression when the tool creates the backing code.